# how to set uitoolbar's background similar to my navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, ios-4.2

Hello everyone:
I have set a custom background for my navigation bar, it's a tint color i think that i chose from IB. Now i want to change the my uitoolbar's (added programmatically) background similar to my navigation bar, programmatically. Obliged for any help in this regard.

Sorry guys my bad it's actually navigation controller's toolbar. so this worked for me:
`self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor=self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;`

Thanks all of u guys for quick response especially @phooze which set me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UIToolbar also has a `tintColor` property, just like a UINavigationBar.  You should be able to set one to the other:

```
myToolbar.tintColor = myNavBar.tintColor;
```

after you create your toolbar.  Keep in mind that this code would only work if myNavBar had been loaded from the NIB, so it would be best to put this in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLoad`.

You can access the UINavigationBar from the `navigationBar` property of UINavigationController (probably s`elf.parentViewController` in your case).

Comment: I've already tried this phooze.. not working out in my case.    I am doing this in my viewWillAppear:  self.toolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;

Comment: Can you confirm at that point in code that both items are non-nil?

Answer (score 2):

There no way to compare the colors of navigation bar and tool bar but you can set toolbar color with following code

```
    aToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    aToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    aToolbar.alpha = 0.7;
```

or

```
aToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.35 blue:0.45 alpha:0.6];
```

Comment: You're correct that it's not possible to compare colors as far as I know, but you can pass around UIColor objects if you already have one (see my answer above).

Answer (score 1):

I used the following setBarTintColor which worked for me while setTintColor didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default black color for toolbar than you can use

```
UIToolbar *ta;
[ta setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use following code for that..it's working..

toolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;